# How can I use javascript to get the highest value of two variables

Tags: javascript

I have two variables name `var h1` and `var h2` 
each holds some numbers.
i want to get highest value to another variable

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for number comparison?

Comment: Math.max https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: Show an example of what numbers are held in each.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this to get the maximum:

```
var result = Math.max(h1,h2)
```

Comment: i didn't even think of math.max, +1

Comment: this is what i am searching for. i am playing with absolute positioned divs inside relative divs. and need to fix width of relative div according to absolute. thanks for your fast reply.

Answer (score 13):

```
var highestNum = h1 > h2 ? h1: h2;
```

or if you dislike tertiary statements:

```
var highestNum;
if (h1 > h2) { 
    highestNum = h1;
} else {
    highestNum = h2;
}
```

Edit: Interestingly enough, it appears the if-else statement runs much faster than Math.max (on Chrome 21)

http://jsperf.com/jbabey-math-max

Comment: That's exactly what I thought when our answers got downvoted. +1'd you

Comment: @Nile what do you think `Math.max` does internally? 3 guesses ;)

Comment: Well, in Spidermonkey, it calles the js_math_max method which looks something like (almost exactly like) the following. So yes, it does use an if statement. The point is, there's a built in function that can handle this better... http://pastebin.com/kzMhaGkG

Answer (score 7):

```
h1>h2?h1:h2
```

Why would you need jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

<s>Fancy way</s> **The only way it should be done** :

```
var otherVar = Math.max(h1,h2);
```

Long way :

```
var otherVar=0;
if(h1 >= h2)
{
    otherVar = h1;
}
else
{
    otherVar = h2;
}
```

Javascript only, no jQuery.

Comment: @Nile Fixed! Based on the level of this question, it might still look fancy for some homework :-)